# Url query - using a key with multiple values

Tags: 7

I am trying to build a url with a query using the url() function.

```
    $options = array(
        'query' => array(
                'parameter1' => 'value1',
                'parameter2' => 'value1,value2',
        ),
        'absolute' => TRUE,
        'external' => TRUE,
    );
    url ('https://somesite.com/', $options);
```

The URL becomes: `https://somesite.com/?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value1%2Cvalue2`

So commas become encoded as %2C.

How can I build a query that has parameters with multiple values separated by comma?

EDIT: I have to deal with an old API that does not recognize %2C as comma characters, so actual commas have to be present in the end url.

Comment: That's actually correct. Symbols on url parameters are supposed to be encoded on a correctly formatted url. On the server side, they should arrive as commas.

Comment: But I have to deal with an old API which does not decode %2C into commas... so actual commas need to be in the URL.. what i ended up doing is a str_replace on the result of the url() function... but that is very ugly

Comment: Then you must mention that (and any other detail) in the question. Related reading: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

> How can I build a query that has parameters with multiple values separated by comma?

You already have, the commas are just encoded so they can be transported safely as part of the URL.

If you mean how can you stop the `url()` function from encoding special characters: you can't, without editing it. More specifically, you would need to replace its use of [`drupal_http_build_query`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_build_query/7.x) with something that only selectively encodes special characters, much like `drupal_http_build_query` does itself for the `/` character.

The other options you have are

- Do a string replace on the return value from `url` (or parse it and build it up again to your own spec)
- Roll your own `url` function to your own spec
- Contact the maintainers of the API and ask them to fix their decoding bug. Obviously YMMV on that.